# How to add comment into an XML file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How do I add a comment into an XML file using Nokogiri?

For example, I have an existing html file. I want to add `<!--doc-->`. How should I do it so I get:

```
...
<body>
<!--doc-->
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use following code fix:

```
require 'nokogiri'

d = Nokogiri::HTML(%Q(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
))

d.css('body')[0].add_child(Nokogiri::XML::Comment.new(d, "doc"))
puts d.to_s
```

Comment: Way too much work. Nokogiri makes it easy to add nodes simply by using a string. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body></body></html>')
doc.at('body') << '<!-- foo -->'

puts doc.to_html


# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><!-- foo --></body></html>
```

Or you can use a bit longer code:

```
doc.at('body').add_child('<!-- foo -->')
```

Which results in the same thing.

It gets a little more interesting/complicated if `<body>` has more nodes, and you care where the comment goes, but that's still basically locating where you want the comment to be inserted, and then doing one of the above.